# $PSScriptRoot and XML.SelectNodes support for powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I know that $PSScriptRoot is not supported for powershell 2.0 , what is a good alternative ?

also does powershell 2.0 support SelectNodes ?

What are good cmdlets for XML manipulation using 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

$PSScriptRoot doe not work, an alternative

$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

SelectNodes is supported